# React native- Best way to display splash video

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

Im doing a splash video screen in my react-native project,I just wanted to know the best way to place splash video?
senario is like this, for the first time user will complete the sign up process and after that play the splash video? or just play the splash video in the beginning of the application one time?(planing to implement using async storage in react native)

There is another question what if 2 or many users register in same mobile? if I proceed with option 01 then its fine I think. if its like second senario, 2nd user will not see the splash screen right?(planing to implement using async storage in react native)

Can anyone suggest a method or best way to do this?
Manny thanks for your help

Comment: is your question about "playing splash in react native" or "playing splash in general"? it seems your problem is the latter. In general you want to show splash per user (you care about customer not the mobile devices right?). So reset your criteria per sign-up